# Sample zigBee network traffic

Tags: networking, pcap, sniffing, zigbee, data-collection

I'm currently building a project to identify IoT devices on a home network and was wondering if anyone has any idea where I could get my hands on some sample pcaps that include ZigBee traffic on them. I don't currently have the ability to order or have the hardware for sniffing zigBee network traffic and am in a bit of a time crunch so if anyone could help me then I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to interpret your question as "How can I find a packet capture with $protocol". I created a searchable pcap database that you can find protocols with, including ZigBee: https://tshark.dev/search/pcaptable/

[image: Searching for ZigBee]

To find ZigBee pcaps, search with `[zbee` in the protocol filter to find pcaps, where

- `[` indicates a protocol. Without this, you'll search pcap descriptions as well.
- zbee is the wireshark display filter family for the [ZigBee protocol](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/z/zbee.nwk.html).